# Shell script to find a string with spaces and wrap with quotes

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to shell scripts. I want to read a file line by line, which contains arguments and if the arguments contains any spaces in it, I want to replace it by enclosing with quotes.

For example if the file (test.dat) contains:

```
-DtestArgument1=/path/to a/text file
-DtestArgument2=/path/to a/text file
```

After parsing the above file, shell script should prepare the string with following:

```
-DtestArgument1="/path/to a/text file" -DtestArgument2="/path/to a/text file"
```

Here is my shell script:

```
while read ARGUMENT; do
    ARGUMENT=`echo ${ARGUMENT} | tr "\n" " "`
        if [[ "${ARGUMENT}" =~ " " ]]; then
            ARGUMENT=`echo $ARGUMENT | sed 's/\^(-D.*\)=(.*)/\1=\"\2\"/g'`
            NEW_ARGUMENT="${NEW_ARGUMENT} ${ARGUMENT}"
        else
            echo "doesn't contains spaces"
            NEW_ARGUMENT="${NEW_ARGUMENT} ${ARGUMENT}"
        fi
    done < test.dat
```

But it's throwing the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 28: Unmatched ) or \)
```

The code should be compatible with all shells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sed` parentheses should be escaped:

```
ARGUMENT=`echo $ARGUMENT | sed "s/\^\(-D.*\)=\(.*\)/\1=\"\2\"/g"`
```

One place you did, in 3 places you forgot... BTW, I generally use `"` quotation.

If you prefer `'`-style, do like this:

```
ARGUMENT=`echo $ARGUMENT | sed 's/\^(-D.*)=(.*)/\1="\2"/g'`
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should simplify the problem.  Rather than worrying about spaces, just quote the argument after the `=`.  Something like:

```
sed -e 's/=/="/' -e 's/$/"/' test.dat | paste -s -d\  -
```

Should be sufficient.  If you really care about spaces, you could try something like:

```
sed -e '/=.* /{ s/=/="/; s/$/"/; }' test.dat | paste -s -d\  -
```

That will only notice spaces after the `=`.  Just use `/ /` if you really want to change any line that has a space anywhere.

There's no need to use a `while/read` loop: just let sed read the file directly.

Comment: +1; just in case it confuses others, too: `-d\ ` is the same as: `-d ' '`; i.e.: use a single space as the delimiter (separator); `paste -s -d\  -` therefore joins all (stdin) input lines with a space to form a single, space-separated output line.

Comment: The side-effect of using `-d\  -` is that you need two spaces after the backslash; it might not be obvious to many.  Better to use `-d' ' -` as @mklement0 suggests.